# oAuth2 authentification with Deezer on mobile with manage_library perms

Tags: oauth-2.0, deezer

I try to make oAuth authentification on iOS with perms set with "manage_library,basic_access,email".

After login, only basic_access is suggested by the Deezer WEB authentification page ?

Where is the issue ?

Why Deezer does not use "standart" oAuth2 mechanism with scope parameters ?

Comment: Could you give us the snippet on how you make the request please?

Comment: found the solution, my oauth library set a default scope (scope: app) and this default scope seems an issue for Deezer oAuth. removing the scope make authentification success